# Access PHP Array by String

Tags: php, string, object

I'm currently looking for a way to access an object via string. For example:

`{
    event: ‘event name’
    metadata: ‘event metadata’ - specified in userCompletedAction withState
    event_timestamp: 'time stamp for the event'
    hardware_id: 'IDFA' (iOS) | 'Android ID' (Android)
}`

Now there should be a parser, for example if I supply the string `hello {{ object.event.metadata.ip }}` it should return `hello 127.0.0.1`.

I thought about exploding the string and foreach it. Is there any name for what I'm looking for?

Best regards

Comment: Is this a PHP array or a PHP object?

Comment: are you trying to [serialize](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.serialize.php) your object ? I don't really understand